# How to detect error after ineffective submit in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, submit

I've just started using Selenium and I can successfully fill a form and click the submit button using the examples code, however I get an error message (which only appears written in the website after submitting, not an actual coding error) which says "There has been an error, try again".

It seems to me the website somehow knows I'm not filling the form manually, and it doesn't like that.

Is that the case ? What can I do in such cases ?

EDIT: This is the website with the form I'm trying to submit:
https://www.alitalia.com/it_it/special-pages/richiesta-rimborso-volo-cancellato.html

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Can you link the website, so I can have a closer look, you may need to add some bot detection code but I can't be certain until I can check the website.

Comment: sure, I've added the link in the post (website in italian, but it doesn't really matter). I get a red error message near the submit button when I use Selenium